# How to change created_at format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord, date-format, datecreated

This should be a simple thing. Well, Im sure it should be simple, this is rails.

The problem is: in the model all data has a field *created_at*. to retrieve this info in the view I use a block, where is a line *t.created_at*.

It shows me a result like *2015-04-12 11:04:44 UTC*

Which method should I use to show this date as *2015-04-12*?
As I suppose it should be something like that:
*t.created_at.date_only*

Could you help me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can read more about `strftime` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)

```
t.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 16):

And it can be done even easier way:

```
t.created_at.to_date
```

Comment: sorry for asking simple questions, but : where do you put that ? in application_controller ?

Answer (score 2):

Or with locales:

```rb
// view:
<% @articles.each do |c| %>
    <%= l c.created_at.to_date, format: :short %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we resort to the following technique, but I don't recommend it

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def created_at
    attributes['created_at'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  end
end
```